# Why do we use tangent to find argument of complex number?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Is it obligatory to use the tangent function for finding the argument of a complex number or can we also use $\sin$ or $\cos$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need more detail to describe what you mean.

Comment: The angle is related to the *slope* of the line segment connecting that number to the origin: if the number lies on the line $y = mx$ and $\theta$ is the angle that segment makes with the positive $x$-axis convince yourself that $m = \tan \theta$ (example: points on the $y = x$ in the first quadratic, where the slope is $1$, have $\theta = \pi/4 = 45^\circ$ and $\tan \theta = 1$). Lesson: the value of $\tan \theta$ is *very* related to the argument in a way that $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ individually are not, even though any one of these numbers determines all of them up to a $\pm$ sign.

Comment: To find $\arg(a+ib)$ you can use $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ or $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$ or $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$ with some adjustment for the signs of $a$ and $b$

Comment: We actually use the function $\operatorname{atan2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what a complex number looks like on the complex plane.

[image]

We already know the sides opposite the angle and adjacent the angle $a,b$. We could calculate the hypotenuse, but that takes more time, so why calculate it? So, since we are using the sides opposite and adjacent, we use the trigonometric ratios that use the opposite and adjacent sides, and these ratios are cotangent or tangent. Hope this helps.